# Мерцающее фиксированное меню

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, господа фронтенд разработчики, ну, или, если проще, верстальщики.

Такая проблема: после прикрепления animate.css и wow.js
прилипающая менюшка стала мерцать в хроме при прокрутке колесом мышки. При прокрутке через скроллбар или стрелочками ничего такого не происходит.

Не могу понять, что происходит.

http://test.z9.kz

Comment: У меня только буковки слегка изменяют свой цвет в хроме, когда меню движется по блоку с изображениями телефонов.